# Spring web context without Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to use Spring to manage my JPA DAOs in web application and trying to follow the Spring website examples to figure out how to do it.

I am considering to use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` instead of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to bootstrap Spring.

In the examples, it is used together with `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` but I would like to use it without Spring MVC.

My web.xml looks following:

```
    ...
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foo.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
...
</web-app>
```

My configuration class looks following:

```
...
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.foo.service"})
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {

            @Override
            public String getMessages() {
                return "Hello Spring World!";
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Is it possible to inject `mockMessageService` in this example into my servlets or do I have to create a separate central hub for my web application where the services are called from by the servlets?

The problem is that if I have my servlets in package `com.foo.service` and try to use

```
@Autowired
```

to get dependancy or try some similar approach the service doesn't get injected and I don't know where's the problem. Is it possible to do it like that? Or should I add something for `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` to work like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlets are managed by the servlet container and not by spring. Spring will not inject servlets, because it does not instantiate them.

If you want to get access to beans managed by spring within a servlet you must do it the same way as spring's `DispatcherServlet` does.

E.g. to get the `WebApplicationContext` from the `ServletContext` do

```
 javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext = ...;
 WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

This works because the `ContextLoaderListener` ensures that the `WebApplicationContext` is available as a `ServletContext` attribute.

Since the `WebApplicationContext` is an `ApplicationContext` you can autowire beans that have been instantiated outside the spring container.

For example

```
ApplicationContext appContext = ...;
AutowireCapableBeanFactory acbf = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean();
acbf.autowireBean(someBean);
```

Just put the `@Autowired` annotation on fields of `SomeBean`.

A much easier way is to extend spring's `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet` and implement the `doService` method. Read the javadoc of the [FrameworkServket](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) for details.

Comment: Good explanation and doing injecting explicitly seems solid enough approach to me. Will try that one now. Unfortunately can't extend FrameworkServlet.

Comment: Going to accept this answer because of good overall picture and thorough explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a servlet, you can wire it up on the init method using something like the below:

```
public class MyServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

  @Autowired
  MyBean myBean;

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory=WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(arg0.getServletContext()).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(this);
  }
 //....
}
```

If I have have a lot of servlets, it can be handy to extract the init method into some reusable parent class e.g.

```
public class AutowiredServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory=WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(arg0.getServletContext()).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(this);
  }
}
```

and extend that class for every servlet that requires Autowiring.